# Bad built Unity to Oculus DK2 but Nice Emulation?

Tags: oculus, oculus-runtime

I am starting to develop an application in Unity 5.1.2f and integrate Oculus Utilities for Unity V0.1.0-beta.
In Player Setting->Others Settings : I have checked "Virtual Reality Supported". 
When I click on "Run Button" in Unity the application starts in my Oculus DK2 and it looks great but when I built the app for "PC , Mac & Linux Standalone " it also works on the Oculus but the two view interfer and do not show a clear image  . the left side is too far from the right side.

So how can I configure the building to get a nice view like the one I see when emulating directly in Unity ?

Thanks for help!

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: we checked all build settings and started to uncheck one by one. we did not know exactly wich setting is the key.but basically we messed up with the build settings that's all